# How to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS in the ASP.NET page lifecycle?

Tags: asp.net, http, iis-7, ssl, https

I have an ASP.NET page that has a lot of server controls added. When a user visits the page from HTTP I need to redirect the request to use HTTPS instead. The controls are dynamically loaded in the `Init` method and I'm doing the redirect in the `Load` method. But this ends up creating a loop that loads the controls and then redirects continuously.

Which event in the page lifecycle can I use to handle the redirect that avoids the loop?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the Gloabal.asax file to do that..try this
code..

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if ( !Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
                string path = string.Format("https{0}", Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Substring(4));

                Response.Redirect(path);
        }
}
```

Comment: i got it wot u all are trying to say.and main problem is my dynamically control loading.because of it all event are firing on control loading  again and again. thats what making redirection continuously and it cant be brows.

Comment: yah you should prevent that and then you can achieve redirection

Comment: Also, you should accept answers to your questions if you've found them to be useful(See there is a tick there)and also use upvotes. It will help you get more answers for your questions

Comment: thanks i have to prevent that.but it is again and again repeating so m unable to handle this cuz page is not posting back .conrols events r firing up its page load event of every control on that page..so lil confusing here i'm

Answer (score 1):

The earliest point in the [page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) you can hook into and redirect from is the Page_PreInit event so I would suggest carrying out your scheme check and redirect here.

Comment: Actually you could do it where-ever you want in the lifecycle, I do mine typically in OnInit.

Comment: i got it wot u all are trying to say.and main problem is my dynamically control loading.because of it all event are firing on control loading again and again. thats what making redirection continuously and it cant be brows.

Answer (score 0):

You should use IIS Rewrite to do this if it is available. The rule is:

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect at the start of your page init if you don't want the controls loaded. I use something like this to redirect (I just emit the code I want):

```
protected void RedirectPage(string redirectUrl)
{
    // Redirect the page, nothing should be shown in this case
    if (redirectUrl.StartsWith("~"))
        redirectUrl = ResolveClientUrl(redirectUrl);
    Response.Write("<head id=\"pageheader\">");
    Response.Write("</head>");
    Response.Write("<body onload=\"window.location = '" + redirectUrl + "';\">");
    Response.Write("</body>");
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: well thanks for reply .I'm using dynamic routing and loading controls dynamically and when loading each controls in global asax begin_request execute repeatedly not only this all page load event are firing  on control loading. so it is becoming very hard to me

Comment: Nothing will have been written out at the start of the page init so I normally just add a call to the function above as the first line. The controls will have been initialized but that should not be a problem. It's probably a bit of a brute force approach but it works really nicely for security checks.

Comment: i found that when i redirect  it redirects and again started to load controls during this time again it redirects and again started to load control .this is why it never completes ive tried on global asax ,page init load preinit not working ..:C

Comment: I assumed that you always wanted to redirect to https when you found a user connected via http. In that case you should do a check if a user is on http and only then redirect to https. When would you be redirecting a user to https?

Comment: One further thing, you should put this in the page init and not in the control init.